# Linq to SQL database management

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

So i am having a real issue with this. I wan add a foreign key to a row i am adding to a database. I have all my references setup so they all map up perfectly fine.

The issue is that i want to add the key without running the query until all rows are submitted.

example tables

```
**FirstNameTable**    **LastNameTable**        **People-Table**
Id | Value            Id | Value               Id | FirstNameID | LastNameID 
----------------      ---------------          ------------------------------
1  | Jeff             1  | jones               1  | 1           | 3          
2  | Joe              2  | Richards            2  | 2           | 1          
3  | John             3  | bobson              3  | 3           | 2
```

So Table3 has 3 foreign keys (FirstNameId links to FirstNameTable, LastNameId links to LastNameTableand ParentId links to People-Table). For the sake of this example lets just say that there will never be a person that has the same first and last name.

I want to add a new entry for table 3 but i want it to either use an existing entry if it is there or create a new one.

Now doing

```
People-Tabletb3 = new People-Table()
{
    FirstNameTable = new FirstNameTable(){ Value = Jeff};
    LastNameTable= new LastNameTable(){ Value = jones};
}
```

Will always create a new entry in my other two tables. Doing the following for each row in each table

```
if ((from u in dc.Users where u.Name == name select u).Count() > 0)
    // just grab the id
else
    // make it then grab the id
```

Isn't really an option because you are then doing more queries and slowing down the upload.

So my question is how do i create a new People-Table row using LINQ that will use an existing row for the first and last name or create a new one if it doesn't exist. Without doing the if-else stuff.

Comment: Is this really a requirement? Alternatively you could make a composite key of [FirstName] and [LastName] in `People-Table`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The question is more about how to either add or use a element from another table depending on if it already exists or not without having to use additional to many queries. I have about 500 - 600 rows to enter each time and running an additional query for each row just for checking increase the submission time quite significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a list of all the distinct names in your list of entries that you're trying to insert.
2. Create a query that pulls all of the values from the Users table, whose names are found in the list you just created. Put these values into a dictionary, keyed by their name.
3. Loop through the entries you want to insert, and for each of those, either associate them with a value from the dictionary you created, or create a new value and add it to the dictionary.

This should do what you're asking, for any number of new entries, in two round-trips total.

Comment: So there isn't a way to do this all through a single query using linq or at least in a single 'submitChanges()'?

Comment: The way I describe will allow you to do it all in a single call to `SubmitChanges()`. This approach will require one query beforehand, no matter how many entries you are trying to create. But no, there's no way in LINQ to SQL to issue commands that will either insert or update objects. Another possibility would be to create a view with triggers, so that you just issue "insert" statements, and the database translates those into inserts or updates accordingly.

Comment: I have made use of your first answer, it doesn't allow me to upload my data as fast (i am doing other stuff as well), but its still a significant improvement. The only way i could figure out was to effectively have the system write a query and execute that on the server. But this way is easier to maintain. Thanks